# Creating ExcelAddin in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, ms-office, office-addins

i want to create an excel AddIn .it is simple :

File>New Project > Visual Basic > Office > Version 2010>OK

but an error says "Object reference  not set to an inctance of an object"!

my VS version is 2010 ultimate
with Office 2010

in addition , i downloaded these two files and inistalled them hope they  help me but it makes no change for me

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=3508

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20479

what is wrong and what is the solution?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have done default VS 2010 installation after Office installation it should work. I would recommend you to repair or reinstall with Office developer tools checked.

Check Microsoft Office section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx)

Comment: thank for ur reply kiru but i reinstalled VS and problem is not solved

Comment: Do you see "Microsoft Office Developer Tools" in Help => About Microsoft Visual Studio menu.

Comment: Do you have two versions of Office installed like 2007 and 2010 together

Comment: There is a discussion over the same thing here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vsto/thread/810110f4-7ab1-461e-a64f-803be25f342d